# Occurrences of a sentence/word/char in a sentence - count only words (no regex if possible) (PHP)

Tags: php, sentence

I am looking for a way to find the number of sentence occurrences in another sentence

For example (I have):

```
Do you have a different language or operating system? JavaScript is currently disabled in your browser and is required to
```

and I am searching for:

> a

This should present me the result of:

> result = 1

because if you count a as a word and not as a char you will get 1 as result:

"Do you have **a** different language or operating system? JavaScript is currently disabled in your browser and is required to"
Din.

Comment: i thin you are looking for [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed use `substr_count`.

To make sure you only match words: add a space before and after the word before using `substr_count` and explicitly check for the word at the start or end of the string using `substr`.

Comment: Or add a space to the start and end of a word, like `" " . $string . " "`, which would then allow you to count `" a "` with one call to `substr_count()`.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant Eric, but you then miss the 'a ' at the start and ' a' at the end of the string, so therefore do two additional `substr` checks.

Comment: You can explicitly check that case as well. With regular expressions you can match an optional dot.

Comment: @dinbrca That's exactly what Coert and I are talking about: Putting a space on either side of the string to search will allow that. See: http://codepad.org/fORXYur3

Comment: @Eric but what if you have "a potato is a.." how would u count the last a? ("a..")

Comment: `str_replace(array('.', '?', '"', /* etc */), ' ', $string);` first.

Answer (score 1):

As far as counting the number of times the WORD "a" is used in a string quickly/simply:

```
$sent = "Do you have a different language or operating system? JavaScript is currently disabled in your browser and is required to";

if( preg_match( '/ a /', $sent, $matches ) ) { # a space before and after makes it a word not a letter.
    echo count( $matches );            
}
```

But that still won't tell you how many sentences there are for sure in all cases; to do that would require a pretty complicated regex.

--> EDIT:

To get the word "a" at the beginning of a sentence and anywhere else, you could do this:

```
$sent = "A different language or operating system? JavaScript is currently disabled in your browser and is required to eat a walrus";

$patterns = array( '/ a /', '/A /' );
$ctr = 0;

foreach( $patterns as $p ) {

    if( preg_match( $p, $sent, $matches ) ) {
        $ctr += count( $matches );             
    }

}

echo $ctr;
```

Comment: The OP asked for it without regex, if possible (and it *is* possible).

Comment: He also is "looking for a way to find the number of sentence occurrences in another sentence" which _may not_ be possible without regex. @Eric

Comment: That is possible without regex as well.

Comment: How would you do it without regex with a sentence like this: 'Mr. Ree gasped, "My God! Where is my cheese!?" and then watched TV.' @Eric

Comment: If he doesn't care what the word boundary is, you can do it with a simple `substr_count()`, again. Even if this is the case, though, the OP never specified that he would need a word boundary other than " ".

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution but seems to give you what you need.

```
$search = 'a';
$str = "Do you have a different language or operating system? JavaScript is currently disabled in your browser and is required to";
$count = array_sum(array_map(function($val) use ($search) {if ($val == $search) { return 1; } else { return 0; }}, str_word_count($str, 1)));
```

Comment: See docs for [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php). Note: this could get pretty gnarly with large chunks of text

Comment: seems like Coert Metz solution can be better, am I wrong?

Comment: It's an altogether better solution probably if speed of execution is a concern. Still - they both do the trick :) You could replace the array_map in my solution with a call to [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) which would probably make it LOOK a little less complicated but ultimately amounts to the same thing.